# Solve and plot differential equation

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want to solve this differential equation

$\qquad y'(x)=\frac{x-y(x)}{1-y(x)-x}$

and plot it's solution. But `DSolve`  doesn's work.

```
DSolve[{y'[x] == (x - y[x])/(1 - x - y[x])}, y[x], x]
```

> ```
> Solve[
>     2 ArcTan[(-x + y[x])/(-1 + x + y[x])] + C[1] + 2 Log[-1 + 2 x] +
>       Log[(1 - 2 x + 2 x^2 - 2 y[x] + 2 y[x]^2)/(-1 + 2 x)^2] == 0, 
>     y[x]]
> ```

How can I plot such an expression?

I tried this:

```
ContourPlot[
  2*ArcTan[(-x + y)/(-1 + x + y)] + 2*Log[-1 + 2*x] + 
    Log[(1 - 2*x + 2*x^2 - 2*y + 2*y^2)/(-1 + 2*x)^2] == 0, 
  {x, -0, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

There is another problem. I don't have an initial condition of the form  $y(x_{0})=c_0$, but I know that $x(0)=0$ and $y(0)=0$.

This differential equation comes from the physics and I know that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ is a velocity, and I can split this equation into two parts and introduce the parametric velocities $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $\frac{dx}{dt}$. Then

```
DSolve[{y'[t] == x[t] - y[t], x'[t] == 1 - x[t] - y[t], x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0},{x[t], y[t]}, t]
```

> ```
> {{x[t] -> 1/2 E^-t (-Cos[t] + E^t Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t] + E^t Sin[t]^2), 
>   y[t] -> 1/2 E^-t (-Cos[t] + E^t Cos[t]^2 - Sin[t] + E^t Sin[t]^2)}}
> ```

With this I can plot the solution.

```
ParametricPlot[
  {1/2 E^-t (-Cos[t] + E^t Cos[t]^2 + Sin[t] + E^t Sin[t]^2), 
   1/2 E^-t (-Cos[t] + E^t Cos[t]^2 - Sin[t] + E^t Sin[t]^2)}, 
  {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

Why doesn't *Mathematica* automatically do this transformation for me?

Answer (score 5):

To answer your question

> Why doesn't Mathematica automatically do this transformation for me?

*Mathematica* don't know that x is a function of t. But you can solve your system directly:

```
sol = NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == (x - y[x])/(1 - y[x] - x), y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}]
```

You get an error message:

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At x == 0.603939625832659`, step size is
>   effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

```
{x1, x2} = sol["Domain"] // First
Plot[sol[x], {x, x1, x2}, AxesLabel -> {x, y[x]}]
```

[image]